# Gidview item not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

My page having city listing and searching functionality. When page first time loading, it is showing all record.

When user enter search Text and tap on search button. it is not updating gridview list. I check by placing debug point my code is working fine. but gridview list not showing updated list.

Following is my code.

XAML:

```
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                </StackPanel>

                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DistanceTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="XXXm" />
                                <Image Width="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/arrowright.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Height="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" Margin="0,3,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Margin="0,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" PlaceholderText="Search" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="50" />
                    <Image x:Name="imgSearch" Height="50" Width="50" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/btnSearch.png" Tapped="imgSearch_Tapped"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

C#:

```
   public List<City> gs_CityList = new List<City>();

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        fillCityList();
    }

    private void fillCityList()
    {
        gs_CityList.Clear();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CityListManagerManager.ms_searchTxt))
        {
            foreach (City foCity in CityListManagerManager.ms_CityList)
            {
                City loCity = new City();
                loCity.Description = foCity.Description.Replace("\n", "").Substring(0, 15) + "...";
                loCity.longtitude = foCity.longtitude;
                loCity.latitude = foCity.latitude;
                loCity.Location = foCity.Location;
                gs_CityList.Add(loCity);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (City foCity in CityListManagerManager.ms_CityList.Where(p => p.Description.ToLower().Contains(CityListManagerManager.ms_searchTxt.ToLower())))
            {
                City loCity = new City();
                loCity.Description = foCity.Description.Replace("\n", "").Substring(0, 15) + "...";
                loCity.longtitude = foCity.longtitude;
                loCity.latitude = foCity.latitude;
                loCity.Location = foCity.Location;
                gs_CityList.Add(loAEDPin);
            }

            txtSearch.Text = CityListManagerManager.ms_searchTxt;
        }

        if (gs_CityList.Count > 0)
        {
            gvCityList.DataContext = gs_CityList;       // --- This binding data to gridview
        }
        else
            MessageBox("City not found...!");
    }

    private void imgSearch_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CityListManagerManager.ms_searchTxt = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
        fillCityList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try changing your `List<City>` into an `ObservableCollection<City>`, as this allows the binding to get notified about changes.

You could also think about using a `CollectionViewSource` as data source for the `GridView` and modifying its `Filter` property instead of re-filling the collection.